# How to delete string before the first occurrence of a delimiter and after the last occurrence of a delimiter in MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to delete the strings before the first occurrence, and after the last occurrence of the delimiter? The delimiter is an underscore "_".

Sample data is:

```
[
  {
    "originalValue": "DELETERANDOMVALUE_Keep_This_Words_DELETERANDOMVALUE"
  }
]
```

The expected result should be:

```
[
  {
    "cleanedValue": "Keep_This_Words"
  }
]
```

With the below code, the string before the first occurrence of the delimiter is removed. But I am unable to delete the strings after the last occurrence.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      cleanedValue: {
        $substr: [
          "$originalValue",
          {
            $add: [
              {
                $indexOfBytes: [
                  "$originalValue",
                  "_"
                ]
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          {
            "$strLenBytes": "$originalValue"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is a [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1n8Gmp6m8_P) I used.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find `first` and `last` unwanted parts using `$regexFind` and then use `$replaceAll` to replace them with empty strings. Like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "first": {
        "$regexFind": {
          "input": "$originalValue",
          "regex": "^([^_]*)_"
        }
      },
      "last": {
        "$regexFind": {
          "input": "$originalValue",
          "regex": "_([^_]*)$"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      originalValue: {
        "$replaceAll": {
          "input": {
            "$replaceAll": {
              "input": "$originalValue",
              "find": "$first.match",
              "replacement": ""
            }
          },
          "find": "$last.match",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6tgBFx2vJy7)

Answer (score 1):

Try to split the string into an array, remove the first and last element and return the joined string:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // Phase 1: split the string by '_'
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      splitValue: {
        $split: [
          "$originalValue",
          "_"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  // Phase 2: remove the first and last element from the array
  {
    $project: {
      cleanedValue: {
        $slice: [
          "$splitValue",
          1,
          {
            $subtract: [
              {
                $size: "$splitValue"
              },
              2
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  // Phase 3: join the remaining elements into a string separated by '_'
  {
    $project: {
      finalValue: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$cleanedValue",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $concat: [
              "$$value",
              // This condition avoids adding a '_' as leading character
              {
                "$cond": [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$value",
                      ""
                    ]
                  },
                  "",
                  "_"
                ]
              },
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gXxHw6GdqnE) to playground.